# Should I install Docker on Server Having Cpanel already on it?

Tags: docker, cpanel, forum, discourse

I want to install Discourse on my server and it needs docker to work. I already have WHM with Cpanel installed on Centos 6 dedicated server, should I install docker or it will create problems?

If it's okay to install Docker on my server then should I install it on a single site or on the whole server via root?,  I need to run 2 copies on discourse on two different domains.

Also, let me know if there will be any performance issue after installing Discourse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found anyone who has answered this question. I too am wondering the same.

However, I'm going to go ahead and try it.

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Create a Centos 7 fresh install server (as I have had issues with docker setups on Centos 6 previously and was told repeatedly Centos 7 fixes those issues).
2. Manually (via command line) setup WHM.
3. Submit ticket to have cPanel license assigned to our new server (I was told this was not supported, only to correct the staff telling me so with reference to another ticket telling me I have to request they assign a cpanel license to my Centos 7 setup, as vultr.com does not as of yet have a one click app install for WHM/Cpanel on Centos 7.) Cpanel license was then assigned to my Centos 7 server after correcting staff member.
4. After all WHM/Cpanel setup completed and working like a charm (including installing CSF for WHM)... I took a snapshot of the server so I can restore it if all else fails.
5. Waiting for snapshot to finish, reading up on requirements for docker and discourse, then will attempt to set the same up on the same server...

Server Specs (Vultr.com):

> 4 vCore
>   RAM: 8192 MB
>   Storage: 100 GB SSD
>   Bandwidth: 4000 GB (0%)
>   OS: CentOS 7 x64

I will return and relate my experience and steps taken to have both running.

FYI. I am not a server admin whatsoever, but a noob who can learn tech stuff enough to get by. I have setup docker droplets on digital ocean successfully a few times, so I hope I can combine the two to see if I can get both working on the same instance rather than pay for two separate servers for both Discourse/Docker and WHM/Cpanel.

---

I followed this tutorial:
[link](https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-discourse-on-centos-7)

I Skipped `Setup Swap File` as my server has enough ram. 
I also made sure to disable SELinux.

> nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux (disabled, then reboot server)
>   sestatus

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the same situation.

Don't forget to share your experience.

Comment: How did it go ?

Comment: How did it go?
I want to install Docker on my WHM server running on centOS, I want to know if it is a safe thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

Just run this command:

curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | bash

and be happy!